# android mqtt ssl connection not working in android 7

Tags: android, ssl, mqtt

I am working on mqtt SSL connection using paho(https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android). The connection is not working in Android Nougat and this working well bellow Android 7.

I am getting  the following exception:

> Mqttjavax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

I am using the bellow code to connect with mqtt.

```
final MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(MainActivity.this, "ssl://" + pref.getMqttUrl(), clientId, persistence);

    try {
         String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();

         MqttConnectOptions connectionOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
         connectionOptions.setCleanSession(true);

        Log.e("Test", "ssl://" + pref.getMqttUrl());

        try {
            InputStream trustStoresIs = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ca_key);


            String trustStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(trustStoreType);
            trustStore.load(trustStoresIs, context.getString(R.string.bks_password).toCharArray());

            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(trustStore);

            InputStream keyStoreStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.user_cer_key);
            KeyStore keyStore = null;
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, context.getString(R.string.bks_password).toCharArray());

            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = null;
            keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, context.getString(R.string.bks_password).toCharArray());

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) context.getSocketFactory();
            connectionOptions.setSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory);

        } catch (KeyManagementException | CertificateException | KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mqttAndroidClient.connect(connectionOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                Log.e("Mqtt","Connection Success!");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                Log.e("Mqtt","Connection Failure!");

            }
        });

        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                Log.e("Mqtt","Connection was lost!");

            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {



            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                System.out.println("mqtt Delivery Complete!");
            }

        });


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: MQTT is working fine in android 7, actually you are not getting path of key store then you are facing this issue. Read about how provider changes in android 7.

Comment: I have checked the path and it is correct only. Can you please suggest something?